# Python numpy simple way to filter label zero from train dataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a train dataset trainX and trainy.
TrainX shape is (n,128,3) trainy shape is (n,1).

I would like to remove all samples where the trainy label is zero. I have the following code which is half working, but some of the dimensions of the numpy arrays are lost.

```
# load the dataset, returns train and test X and y elements
def load_dataset_train_only(prefix='trainingData128/'):
    # load all train
    trainX, trainy = load_dataset_group('train', prefix)            
    print(trainX.shape, trainy.shape)
    # zero-offset class values
    trainy = trainy

    #remove samples where stroke rate = 0
    train_filter = np.where(trainy != 0)
    trainX, trainy = trainX[train_filter], trainy[train_filter]
    print('Size after filtering off zero labels',trainX.shape, trainy.shape)
            
    # one hot encode y
    trainy = to_categorical(trainy)
    print(trainX.shape, trainy.shape)
    return trainX, trainy
```

The shape before filtering is;
(366511, 128, 3) (366511, 1)

And the shape after filtering is;
Size after filtering off zero labels (280905, 3) (280905,)

The 280905 value is correct, so it is filtering the zero labels, but how do I modify the code so I don't loose the dimensions?

Thanks

Comment: `train_filter = np.where(trainy != 0)[0]` or `trainy[train_filter, :]`?

Comment: Yes, train_filter = np.where(trainy != 0)[0] worked if you want to post it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an `n-D` array, `np.where` returns indices for all the `n` dimensions, so:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> arr
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> np.where(arr > 3)
(array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64))
```

So as you only want the first dimension, you should use:

```
train_filter = np.where(trainy != 0)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.nonzero()` to filter out element that aren't zero.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(0, 3, (10, 1))
```

```
array([[0],
       [2],
       [2],
       [0],
       [0],
       [2],
       [0],
       [1],
       [0],
       [2]])
```

```
not_zero, _ = np.nonzero(x)
```

```
array([1, 2, 5, 7, 9], dtype=int64)
```